# What is Virtual folder in SDL Tridion

Tags: 2011, 2013

Someone asked a question to me that "what is Virtual folder in Tridion and what is use of this".

i got something below text in SDLlivecontent

> A Virtual Folder is an item that can contain different types of
>   content items located in different locations in Content Manager

and

> In the TOM.NET and Core Service APIs, Virtual Folders are a class of
>   item. To the end user, Virtual Folders present themselves in two
>   different ways:  Search Folders Search Folder represent a search query
>   performed on Content Manager. The contents of a Search Folder are
>   dynamically determined whenever a user examines its contents. Bundles
>   A Bundle is a collection of content items for the purpose of
>   collective processing, including applying a Workflow Process to the
>   items collectively.

Is it something which can be created in CME similar to Folders ? if yes , How it is different with Folder in SDL tridion.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`VirtualFolder` is not a folder in itself, in a sense that it doesn't contain any items, but rather links to items that are stored in other places. Let's consider `SearchFolder` and `Bundle` separately.

- SearchFolder is search result, it shows you items that match your criteria, but are stored in different places. You can create `SearchFolder` by clicking new VirtualFolder in CME, or searching for something and saving results
- Bundle is simply a virtual container. You add links to items, but not the items itself. You can create it in CME (introduced in Tridion 2013)

Virtual folders is a convenient way of grouping items, for example you may want to see all items, modified in the last few days (SearchFolder), or want to group items for you upcoming campaign (Bundle)

Comment: thanks for answering, i am trying to create a virtual folder and getting the error "Invalid Search Location was provided
Source tab validation error: the search location (SearchIn XML node) must be an organizational item inside the current Publication.". Could you please brief me about the issue

Comment: Switch to advanced search and save result. Check configuration tab of virtual folder, you will see your query and "searchIn". You problem is that you didn't set searchIn in the configuration tab:   <SearchIn xlink:href="tcm:2-3-2" Recursive="true" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></SearchIn>

Comment: Hi , i am not able to save the search."Save Search ..." button is disable.Is this something permission issue.Even i do'nt think so. Where am i wrong Could u please help me

Comment: If your `SearchIn` is already a publication or a folder/structure group and the button is disabled, try selecting `All Publication` and back to your organizational item.

Comment: Not being able to save a search should probably be a separate question, but the main reasons users can't save a search are either: 1) authorization -- you need search folder rights and write permissions to the folder where you want to save or 2) searching the entire BluePrint or a publication won't let you save the search. You need to first search in a folder or SG before saving a virtual folder.

Comment: I see a need for training. This is really Tridion 1-0-1...